# How to make a python application that has a watchdog if it is closed then it reopens itself

Tags: python

Im trying to make a watchdog for my antivirus it can get terminated easily I dont want that
I tried using Atexit didnt work Its like You know other antiviruses cant get terminated
Also it shall work with pyinstaller please